# How to run mysql commands through shell script?

Tags: mysql, shell-scripting

```
mysql -u root -pmysql;

SELECT TABLE_NAME AS "Table Name", table_rows AS "Quant of Rows", ROUND((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024,2) AS "Total Size Mb"  FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE information_schema.TABLES.table_schema='database_name';
```

I want to create a shell script which will execute these command and return the result.

How may i run this commands through shell script ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
mysql -u root -pmysql << eof
SELECT TABLE_NAME AS "Table Name", table_rows AS "Quant of Rows", ROUND((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024,2) AS "Total Size Mb"  FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE information_schema.TABLES.table_schema='database_name';
eof
```

Answer (score 6):

Yet another answer...

```
mysql -uroot -pmysql -B --skip-column-names -e'SELECT TABLE_NAME AS "Table Name", table_rows AS "Quant of Rows", ROUND((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024,2) AS "Total Size Mb"  FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE information_schema.TABLES.table_schema="database_name"'
```

Also, if you are going to have the password in the script, you should secure it so it isn't readable by people you don't wanting to know the password.

Answer (score 3):

Or, equivalently, something like this:

```
echo 'SELECT TABLE_NAME AS "Table Name", table_rows AS "Quant of Rows", ROUND((data_length + index_length)/1024/1024,2) AS "Total Size Mb" FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE information_schema.TABLES.table_schema="database_name";' | mysql -u root -pmysql
```

EDIT: fixed quoting.

Comment: Getting Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Comment: sorry, got quoting wrong.  adjusted above.

Comment: @PhilHollenback : Is it possible to save the result in a script variable while executing the above line?